# How to Fix Blurry GroupBox Header Text

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

I'm having a strange issue with the clarity of text inside of a GroupBox (using the Material Design for WPF [package](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)).

In design view, everything looks normal:

[image]

However when I build the app, the GroupBox Header text ("Activity Feed:") is suddenly blurry:

[image]

No other controls are suffering this effect. I'm not using any custom styles. See XAML:

```
                        <GroupBox Margin="5 5 15 0" Name="ActivityFeedGroupbox" Header="Activity Feed:" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignGroupBox}" materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth1" BorderThickness="0" Height="205">
                            <ListView Name="FeedListView" Margin="5 0 5 0">
                                <ListView.View>
                                    <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn Width="460">
                                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FeedData}">
                                                        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                                            <ToolTip Background="Gray">
                                                                <StackPanel>
                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tooltip}" Foreground="Black" />
                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                            </ToolTip>
                                                        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                                    </TextBlock> 
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn>
                                    </GridView>
                                </ListView.View>
                            </ListView>
                        </GroupBox>
```

Thoughts on how to fix?

Comment: Try giving it a HeaderContentTemplate which puts the content in a Label that has SnapToDevicePixels=“True”. Or just put SnapToDevicePixels=“True” on the GroupBox itself.

Comment: Settings SnapToDevicePixels=“True” on the GroupBox itself didn't do the trick unfortunately. WPF isn't recognizing HeaderContentTemplate as supported. I'm trying to add it just below the GroupBox declaration.

Comment: Sorry, I misremembered. It's just `HeaderTemplate`. If it's not doing any good on the GroupBox itself, though, I doubt that it'll do any good inside the template. Try giving `UseLayoutRounding="True"` a shot as well.

Comment: Negative on both counts.

Comment: Can you set `Header` as a `TextBlock` element or is some `HeaderTemplate` interfering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to set:

```
 UseLayoutRounding="True"
```

in the containing window.
Another way is to change:

```
<GroupBox Margin="5 5 15 0" ...
```

to

```
<GroupBox Margin="5 6 15 0" ...
```

have a look how physical device pixels work:
https://wpftutorial.net/DrawOnPhysicalDevicePixels.html

Comment: Setting UseLayoutRounding="True" in my window properties fixed this in my case. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` on your `Window`. It's set for default wpf windows, but some custom theme authors forget about this setting.